# Using div's instead of select's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, select

Hello I've implemented a custom select following this instructions:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/06/20/create-a-custom-select-box-with-jquery/

It is based on using div's and span instead of select's and option. My question is, how can I make the form get this values?

Do I need to make hidden select and assign to it the div-select value every time?

Comment: A hidden input is the way to go.

Comment: you can set the attribute like <span id="test1" data-value="option1" >option1</span>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a hidden input somewhere in form, say

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo">
```

Then add this line to the jQuery snippet

```
$(this).find('span.selectOption').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('display','none');
    $(this).closest('div.selectBox').attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
    $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());

    $('input[name="foo"]').val($(this).html());
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Basically, whenever an option is clicked it will update the field named "foo" which stores the name of the selected option.

Comment: Thanks that was what I thought, I wanted to make sure it was necessary. By the way if someone uses it and wants the "default value" to be passed if no other is clicked then just add that line at the start of the jQuery snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hidden select that matches the selected value, or just a hidden input with the updated value. Either way, to be included in the form submission, it must be a `input`, `textarea` or a `select` with a `name` attribute.